# Editable QTreeView with expandable cells

Tags: qt, pyqt

I tried to write an editable table based on QTreeView with wordwraped content in cells which in turn should expand in height (that whole text was visible) like usual cells in tables like in MSWord, but have met insuperable obstacles:

first - i can't set fixed cell size.

second - i can't make text display in cells wordwraped. For this i used void QTreeWidget::setItemWidget ( QTreeWidgetItem * item, int column, QWidget * widget ), but it works only for readonly solutions. And i haven't come up with any other idea.

Can such behavior of QTreeView be realized? And how to solve those problems of mine?

Thanks in advance

Serge

Comment: If you're creating an "editable table" why do you need to base it on QTreeView?

Comment: i just want to have tree structured text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should inherit QTreeView instead of QTreeWidget.
And I fear that you may have to specialize from QAbstractItemView, QAbstractItemDelegate and QAbstractItemModel.

Comment: Can you provide details? What would you do after inheriting and "specialising"?

Comment: 13 years later . In QT at the time, it was usual when you wanted to change a default behavior of your widgets, to inherit from them. Actually the doc would indicate from what class or group of classes you had to do it. From there you would code your own behavior and it would integrate with the default views and widgets correctly. The ability to see the source code was helping a lot to understand how something worked, and what to change when needed.

Comment: I mean a concrete answer would be good. What to inherit, what exactly to customise, etc?